# Moving a div into another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have 2 main div:

```
    <div id="div1">
<div id="minidiv1">a</div>
<div id="minidiv2">b</div>
   </div>
   <div id="div2"></div>
```

I want move the minidiv1 into the div2 with jquery

how can i do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply append it to the *div2*, and it will change its location in the DOM:

```
$('#minidiv1').appendTo('#div2'); 
// or
$('#div2').append('#minidiv1');
```

The difference of the above two lines is what is returned, `appendTo` returns the `#minidiv` element, `append` will return the `#div2` element.

Use the one you find most useful if you want to make more actions (by chaining).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#minidiv1').appendTo('#div2');
```

or

```
$('#div2').append($('#minidiv1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#minidiv1").appendTo("#div2")
```

Answer (score 0):

Luca, did Paul's answer actually work for you?  I think you need to be referencing the jQuery object like so:

```
$($('#minidiv1')).appendTo('#div2'); 
// or
$('#div2').append($('#minidiv1'));
```

Otherwise, jQuery will just append the string "#minidiv1" to #div2, rather than moving your existing div.